# Php como puedo recorrer este array multidimensional

Tags: php, array, php7

Tengo este **array multidimensional** con el nombre `$mensajes` :

```
[0] => Array (
        [id] => 140
        [titulo] => titulo mensaje 1
        [contenido] => contenido mensaje 1
        [createAt] => 2019-04-25 20:27:59
        [creador] => 1
        [url_img] => 5cc1fc2f3462c0.37633589.png
        [etiquetas] => Array (
            [ids] => Array (
                [0] => 90
                [1] => 89
                )
            [nombres] => Array (
                [0] => etiqueta_mensaje_uno
                [1] => comun
                )
            )
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 141
        [titulo] => titulo mensaje 2
        [contenido] => contenido mensaje 2
        [createAt] => 2019-04-25 20:29:15
        [creador] => 1
        [url_img] => 5cc1fc7ba0c713.37620569.png
        [etiquetas] => Array (
            [ids] => Array (
                [0] => 91
                [1] => 89
                )
            [nombres] => Array (
                [0] => etiqueta_mensaje_dos
                [1] => comun
                )
            )
        )
```

Primero por **curiosidad** le hice un `var_dump()`
 pero no me sale todos los datos de este, los `arrays` hijos me los muestra con unos simples puntos `...`, y eso y nada es lo mismo.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '140' (length=3)
      'titulo' => string 'titulo mensaje 1' (length=16)
      'contenido' => string 'contenido mensaje 1' (length=19)
      'createAt' => string '2019-04-25 20:27:59' (length=19)
      'creador' => string '1' (length=1)
      'url_img' => string '5cc1fc2f3462c0.37633589.png' (length=27)
      'etiquetas' => 
        array (size=2)
          'ids' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'nombres' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '141' (length=3)
      'titulo' => string 'titulo mensaje 2' (length=16)
      'contenido' => string 'contenido mensaje 2' (length=19)
      'createAt' => string '2019-04-25 20:29:15' (length=19)
      'creador' => string '1' (length=1)
      'url_img' => string '5cc1fc7ba0c713.37620569.png' (length=27)
      'etiquetas' => 
        array (size=2)
          'ids' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          'nombres' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
```

Probe a **recorrerlos** con un `foreach()` que seria lo logico, pero por lo visto tiene **conflictos**  a la hora de leer los `arrays` **hijos:**

```
foreach ($mensajes as $key ) {
            echo "<p>" . $key['id'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $key['titulo'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $key['contenido'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $key['createAt'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $key['creador'] . "</p>";
            echo "<p>" . $key['url_img'] . "</p>";
            foreach ($key['etiquetas'] as $key2 ) {
                echo "<p>" . $key2['ids'] . "</p>";
                echo "<p>" . $key2['nombres'] . "</p>";
            }
            echo "----------------<br>";

    }
```

Cual es la forma optima para **recorrer** mi `array` que sea de forma **asociativa** claro, sin numeros en los **indices** sino su **clave**

Comment: puedes modificar las propiedades de tus objetos? o lamentablemente tienen que ser asi?

Comment: hombre las he puesto asi porque es la forma mas ordenada para recorrer cada mensaje

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como tienes el array organizado no puedes acceder a los arrays que hay en `etiquetas` usando el for anidado.

El problema es que los arrays están en las claves `ids` y `nombres`, entonces, tendrías que acceder a ellos directamente desde `$key` y empezar a recorrerlos con un for, o usar condicionales o algo así.

La forma más simple podría ser alcanzando los arrays directamente y luego sacar los valores como `implode`.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
$html="";
foreach ($mensajes as $key ) {
    $html.="<p>$key[id]</p>";
    $html.="<p>$key[titulo]</p>";
    $html.="<p>$key[contenido]</p>";
    $html.="<p>$key[createAt]</p>";
    $html.="<p>$key[creador]</p>";
    $html.="<p>$key[url_img]</p>";
    /*Esto en vez del for anidado*/
    $arrIds=$key['etiquetas']['ids'];
    $arrNames=$key['etiquetas']['nombres'];

    $html.= "<p>IDs : <br />".implode("<br>",$arrIds)."</p>";
    $html.= "<p>Nombres : <br />".implode("<br />",$arrNames)."</p>";
    $html.="----------------<br>";
}

echo $html;
```

Salida:

```html
<p>140</p>
<p>titulo mensaje 1</p>
<p>contenido mensaje 1</p>
<p>2019-04-25 20:27:59</p>
<p>1</p>
<p>5cc1fc2f3462c0.37633589.png</p>
<p>IDs : <br />90<br> 89</p>
<p>Nombres : <br />etiqueta_mensaje_uno<br> comun</p>----------------<br>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, a veces veo que n el `foreach` despues de `as $key` se suele poner `=>$value` realmente no tendria `$key` y `$value` el **el mismo valor**

Comment: @josanangel no entiendo la duda de tu comentario. Sí te refieres a cuando hay un formato y dentro otro formato, aunque pongas lo mismo en los dos no habría confusión porque cada for tiene su propio ámbito. Aunque por motivos de legilibildad es mejor diferenciarlos. Yo suelo usar un nombre de variable que identifique el tipo de objeto que se está leyendo. Aquí dejé `$key` porque era lo que estabas usando originalmente.

Comment: me refefira a estas dos cosas principalmente : `foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {
  # code...
 }

 foreach ($variable as $key) {
  # code...
 }` Un saludo y gracias por todo

Comment: @josanangel No, para nada. Se pone `as $key => $value` en los casos en que se necesite el índice de los elementos del array. Ahí `$key` tendría el valor del índice y `$value` el dato o elemento que habrá en cada índice. Nunca tendrían el mismo valor, ni siquiera en los arrays unidimensionales, donde `$key` sería `0,1,2,3...`

Comment: Ah perfecto!, duda aclarada. Mil gracias.